# Mapping a one-way ManyToMany?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to map the following company to the below address. I want it to be a one way relationship since the address class is being used by several other classes.

When I generate the schema the junction table is created successfully but when I try to save an entity nothing is persisted in the junction table. Only in address and company tables. What do I need to do to make this work?

```
public CompanyMapping()
{
    Map(x => x.Name);

    HasManyToMany(x => x.Addresses);
}

public AddressMapping()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);

    Map(x => x.AddressLineOne)
        .Not.Nullable();

    Map(x => x.AddressLineTwo)
        .Nullable();

    Map(x => x.PostCode)
        .Not.Nullable();

    Map(x => x.City)
        .Not.Nullable();
}

public class HasManyToManyCascadeConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.All();
        instance.Inverse();
        instance.Key.ForeignKey(Inflector.Underscore("fk_" + instance.EntityType.Name + "_" + instance.ChildType.Name));
    }
}

<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Company" table="`company´">
    <id name="Id">
        <column name="company_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <bag table="company_address" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" name="Addresses">
        <key column="company_id" />
        <many-to-many class="Address" column="address_id" />
    </bag>
    <property name="Name">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
</class>
```

**EDIT 2010-11-05:** If I add mappings for BillingAddress and DeliveryAddress like this I don't have any problems.

```
References(x => x.BillingAddress)
    .Column("billing_address_id")
    .ForeignKey("fk_account_billing_address")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Fetch.Join();

References(x => x.DeliveryAddress)
    .Column("delivery_address_id")
    .ForeignKey("fk_account_delivery_address")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Fetch.Join();
```

In rails I would use a polymorphic association and I guess this means an Any relationship in NHibernate no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell nHibernate which side of the collection wears the pants. See if this works:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Addresses)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.All();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I updated the code with one of the conventions. I'll post the xml as well

Comment: I've tried with inverse, not inverse. With forreign keys without keys etc etc but it produces the same result. Nothing is persisted in the join-table.

Comment: Are your saves wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: Not when running the unit tests but I have the same issue while debugging the application.

Comment: Did you let nHib auto-create the mapping table (via schema update)? If not you may need to add additional configuration to tell nHib about it.

Comment: Yes it was autocreated but is not being used more than that and my guess is because it's not referenced from the address class / mapping